# Can you tell me how this program is working?

Tags: java, object, instance, inner-classes

If `s1` is referring to the new object created by `f1.switch()`, then
(1) How is variable `runningStatus` passed to the new object created for the inner class?
(2) How is change in variable `runningStatus` done in object of inner class (referred by s1), reflecting in the object of Fan referred by f1?

```
interface Switch
{
    void on();
    void off();
}

class Fan
{
    private boolean runningStatus;
    public Switch getSwitch()
    {
        return new Switch()
        {
            public void on()
            {
                runningStatus = true;
            }
            public void off()
            {
                runningStatus = false;
            }
        };
    }
    public boolean getRunningStatus()
    {
        return runningStatus;
    }
}

class FanStatus
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Fan f1 = new Fan();
        Switch s1 = f1.getSwitch();
        s1.on();
        System.out.println(f1.getRunningStatus());
        s1.off();
        System.out.println(f1.getRunningStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: Inner classes have access to the their enclosing outer class instance variables. And they can modify them.

Comment: Try `Switch mySwitch = new Switch();`. You'll notice that you can't do that because `Switch` is not a `static class`. Since it's not static the class `Switch` is basically a "helper" or a "container" inside `Fan` to organize your code. This is what ergonaut is expressing with `f1.switch.runningStatus = true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(1) How is variable runningStatus passed to the new object created for the inner class?
```

Fan's runningStatus is being accessed by the Switch instance, it's not being passed like a parameter.

```
(2) How is change in variable runningStatus done in object of inner class (referred by s1), reflecting in the object of Fan referred by f1?
```

When the Switch instance changes the variable from Fan's instance, it's actually the same variable.  It's not "passed by value", or "passed by reference", it's more like:

```
f1.getSwitch().on() 

~ is equivalent to ~

f1.switch.runningStatus = true
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The inner class shares the same scope as the variable `runningStatus`, hence it is visible to the inner class. Think of the inner class as another variable within the `Fan` object.
2. The method `getSwitch()` returns the reference of the `Switch` object instantiated when the method was called. hence making any changes to `s1` means you are actually changing the properties of the `Switch` object inside the instance of `Fan`, in this case `f1`, which effectively alters the properties of `f1`.

Answer (score 0):

(1) All the variables can be accessed by the inner Class  actually in the tutorial is knows as anonymous class

[Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

(2) As mentioned in the (1) is the property of the local class or anonymous class access all the variables of the outer class

[Great Inner Outer classes explanation](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/inner-classes-in-java/)